# Position of entry in sqlite ordered table

Tags: sqlite

I'm attempting to order a table and return the position of a row in that ordered table. Just for context, I'm developing a leveling system for a discord bot and trying to implement a rank command. The command will show the user's xp in relation to the rest of the server. eg. "You have 25th most xp in this server". I'm able to order the table with `SELECT * FROM users ORDER by xp DESC` but struggling to get the entry's position. I'd appreciate it if you could give any advice

My table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE "users" (
"guild_id"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
"user_id"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
"xp"    INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
PRIMARY KEY("guild_id","user_id")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use `ROW_NUMBER` for this.**

```sql
SELECT YourRank
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY xp DESC) AS YourRank
    FROM users
) u
WHERE u.user_id = @someId;
```

If you want tied rankings, you can also use `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK`